# Show Dynamic Field Section only on Clone

Tags: clone, visibility, criteria-filter, dynamic-forms

When you enable Dynamic Forms, the 'New Record' form is determined by the Field Sections on your Record Page, instead of using the traditional Page Layout. I like to design custom forms when a user clicks the 'new' button, instead of them just seeing everything so I've made special Field Sections that only show up when `Name == ''`. (I also set all the other field sections to only show up with `Name != ''`)

My problem is with the 'clone' feature. When cloning, Salesforce brings up the 'New Record' form, but since it already has a Name (cloned from the previous record), it doesn't show me the fields that I want for a 'New Record' form. It's shows me the other ones.

I know there are custom solutions I could build, like a modal flow launched from a custom button or something, but is there any way I can filter these field section visibility criteria to target records specifically opened using the 'clone' functionality? The 'Created Date' field doesn't appear to be usuable in the filter criteria.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have access to `ISCLONE` function in the visibility expression, even with Winter '23's update around [this function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isclone.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the soonest that expression can be evaluated is before save, which doesn't work for visibility criteria.